# Why can't I access my 2D array outside of the loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader

I'm having some trouble accessing my 2D array (myArray) outside of this the loop.  I want to access it using other methods, but I can't even access it in this method. It prints out correctly as it's looping, but the test print of

```
System.out.println(myArray[10][2]);
```

is always null.  So it's like the array isn't actually filling or something.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
package titanic;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Titanic {


public static final int ROW = 1309;
public static final int COLUMN = 6;
public static String [][] myArray = new String[ROW][COLUMN];


public static String[][] arraySetup(){

    int recordCounter = 0;
    String[][] myArray = new String[ROW][COLUMN];
    String[] name = new String [ROW];
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/Titanic.txt"));
        String line;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1309; i++){
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

            String tmp[] = line.split("\t");
                myArray[i][0] = tmp[0];
                myArray[i][1] = tmp[1];
                myArray[i][2] = tmp[2];
                myArray[i][3] = tmp[3];
                myArray[i][4] = tmp[4];
                myArray[i][5] = tmp[5];
                System.out.println("myArray[i][5] = " + myArray[i][5]);
                recordCounter++;

            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(myArray[10][2]);

    System.out.println(recordCounter + " records.");
    return myArray;
}
```

Comment: How many rows of data are in your input file? How many did you read?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping first off.  So I fixed it so that the array does initialize correctly, but now I can't seem to access it from other methods.  This method does return myArray, but for some reason the values are all null in other methods.  Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @AnecdotalEvidence Update your question then.

Answer (score 1):

As you have you `while` loop inside `for` loop that is used to for indexing your output array `while` loop always writes into the `myArray[0][0]` to `myArray[0][5]`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1309; i++){   // i is 0
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){   // you go through all the lines while i is 0

        String tmp[] = line.split("\t");
            myArray[i][0] = tmp[0];
            myArray[i][1] = tmp[1];
            myArray[i][2] = tmp[2];
            myArray[i][3] = tmp[3];
            myArray[i][4] = tmp[4];
            myArray[i][5] = tmp[5];
            System.out.println("myArray[i][5] = " + myArray[i][5]);
            recordCounter++;

        }
    }
```

Because of that your check always returns null.

```
System.out.println(myArray[10][2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use for and while loop together. During the first for loop, your while reads all file contents and all other array positions remain empty. 
Try this instead:

```
int i=0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    String tmp[] = line.split("\t");
     myArray[i][0] = tmp[0];
     myArray[i][1] = tmp[1];
     ...       
     myArray[i][5] = tmp[5];

     i++;
     System.out.println("myArray[i][5] = " + myArray[i][5]);
     recordCounter++;
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and once I moved "int i = 0;" outside of my try it worked perfectly!  Now I just can't seem to access the array outside of this method for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your code is right there

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1309; i++){ // you loop 1308 time
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ /* in each loop, you loop 
 until you have read all the file so you read 1308 time the file. But when 
you reach the end of file on the first iterration, it wont read the file on the 1307
 other iterration  and all data will be store in myArray[0][0-5]*/

            String tmp[] = line.split("\t");
                myArray[i][0] = tmp[0];
                myArray[i][1] = tmp[1];
                myArray[i][2] = tmp[2];
                myArray[i][3] = tmp[3];
                myArray[i][4] = tmp[4];
                myArray[i][5] = tmp[5];
                System.out.println("myArray[i][5] = " + myArray[i][5]);
                recordCounter++;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I realized I over-thought the for/while loop structure.